# regex partial match for several different groups

Tags: javascript, regex

I need regexp to match string build from several groups (A is any letter, 9 is any digit):

group 1 regex [A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]?

```
A
A9
AA9
```

group 2 regex [A-Z]{1,3}[0-9]?

```
A
AA
AAA
AAA9
```

group 3 regex [A-Z]{2,3}[0-9]?[A-Z]?

```
AAA
AA9
AA9A
```

group 4 regex [0-9]{1,2}[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]?

```
9A
9AA
9A9
99A9
```

Not each group must be present but there must be all in correct order - I mean (digit is group number):

```
1
12
123
1234
```

So if there is present group 3 there must me all preceding groups present also.

As there are four groups (can be more), so alternative like

```
^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1}|[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1}\s{1}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]?$
```

is not the best option as it would be complicated and difficult to maintain. 
Is there any solution with groups or something? 
The order of groups is important.

Comment: Please, define rules for your groups more precise. Should any group start with `A`? Are groups always delimited by spaces? e t.c.

Comment: always starts with A? Can have more groups like what?
The exame only have A and 9 but your regex have A-Z

Comment: As said: A and 9 represent letters and digits. I edited question to be more precise about groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]?(?:\s+[A-Z]{1,3}[0-9]?(?:\s+[A-Z]{2,3}[0-9]?[A-Z]?(?:\s+[0-9]{1,2}[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]?)?)?)?$
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex will match all the strings you have provided:

```
^[A-Z]+[0-9]*(\s+[A-Z]+[0-9]*)+$
```

and unlimited words.

Comment: But this will not work when there will be more groups and second of 3 will be absent.

Comment: Sure, but when I answered you didn't provide those examples ;)